# Google maps duplicated API key

Tags: android, google-maps

I've got aar dependency in my app. Both my application and dependency uses google maps. The problem is that when im adding api key to manifest i get error about duplicated entries of api key - one is in my app's manifest and the other in dependency's manifest. Is there workaround for this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.gatwick.airport">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.pointrlabs.level11.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".view.base.BaseApplication_"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".view.splashscreen.SplashActivity_"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/icn_notification_small" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
            android:resource="@color/tealBlue" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="net.hockeyapp.android.appIdentifier"
            android:value="@string/hockeyapp_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="firebase_crash_collection_enabled"
            android:value="false" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="75251895b24f9cca963e45138047c6a7d2391bd2"
            tools:replace="android:value"
            />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you post the code of your Manifest please?

Comment: I already edited my post. Check it